# Don't understand the proof that the definite integral of an odd function is $0$

Tags: definite-integrals, proof-explanation

I am a beginner and I'm having trouble making sense of this proof, and I also can't make sense of any of the explanations I find online. I have read the [proofwiki page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definite_Integral_of_Odd_Function), but I have a similar problem to the person in this post:
[Regarding proof of definite integral of odd functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184436/regarding-proof-of-definite-integral-of-odd-functions?newreg=40820eb8e23248558a5bc04660de3f42). Unfortunately none of the answers there help me.

The problem is with the end of the proof. In the beginning of the proof, there is variable substitution, with $u=-x$. Consequently, I also have $\mathrm dx=x'(u)\,\mathrm du$, and I have to change the interval so that $u(-a)=a$ etc.

So far so good. But at end of the proof, they simply replace the $u$ with an $x$. That doesn't make any sense to me. I feel that if I want to go back to the variable $x$, I have to do the subsitution in reverse. I have to change the intervals and add the derivative etc. I can't just replace the $u$ with an $x$ as if they are equal.

In the answers, people say that $u$ is just a dummy variable. But it's not just a dummy variable! If it was, then how come I had to change the intervals and add the derivative $x'(u)$ in the beginning?

Comment: You can call a variable any name you like - changing the name doesn't change the calculation. [Calling two different things by the same name can cause confusion and error]

Comment: How is it not a dummy variable? $\int_0^af(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_0^af(u)\,\mathrm du=\int_0^af(v)\,\mathrm dv=\int_0^af(\widetilde\xi_0)\,\mathrm d\widetilde\xi_0$.

Comment: Any variable over which you integrate becomes a dummy variable. The two integrals are being added together, so you can independently name the variables inside them to be anything you want. It is a dummy variable because once you've computed the integral, it doesn't depend on $u$.

Comment: @MarkBennet were you trying to link something?

Comment: @JohnDoe Not trying to link. The key thing is whether changing the name changes the calculation or not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. These are the exact same explanations as the ones on the previous post, and I just can't understand. I changed the intervals because u = - x, meaning they are not equal. I agree that if I were to calculate the integral, then I wouldn't need to reverse it. The value would be the same. But in this equation, u = - x, meaning x = - u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the step $$\int_0^{-a} f(x)\,dx\underbrace{=}_{x\mapsto-u}-\int_0^af(-u)\,du\color{blue}{=-\int_0^a f(-x)\,dx}$$
The integral $\int_0^af(-u)\,du$ takes values of $u$ from $0$ to $a$ and computes the sum of $f(-u)$ over these values. 
The integral $\int_0^af(-x)\,dx$ takes values of $x$ from $0$ to $a$ and computes the sum of $f(-x)$ over these values.

Do you see why these are both the same, and why $u$ is a dummy variable?

---

An analogy:

$$\sum_{i=-4}^{-1} (-i)\underbrace{=}_{i\mapsto -j}\color{red}{\sum_{j=1}^{4}(j)}=\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^4(i)}$$ Then $$\color{red}{LHS}=1+2+3+4$$ and $$\color{blue}{RHS}=1+2+3+4$$

So even though  you say "$i=-j$", this is not the case, these are both just dummy variables, since the final answer doesn't depend on $i$ or $j$. And so $\color{red}\sum=\color{blue}\sum$.

Comment: Perhaps I have simply learned the rules wrong, because you have not added a -1 when you did the substitution. (I don't know what it's called, the equivalence of the jacobian matrix?)

Comment: @kritters sorry, that was just a typo. the key point is the two sentences below the integrals

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the addition you made. Now it makes more sense to me. I did understand that the values were the same, but it seemed odd to me that one minute u is a function of x, and the next minute it's just a dummy variable. Anyway, thank you for your help and your patience!